# Textarea events - Mouseout / Mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, tabs, uikit

So I'm trying to figure out the right events to preventdefault on for my problem.

I have a UIKit tabs instance on my website with two tabs. One is for writing message and the other for an AJAX load on the preview.

Now when I write a message in the textarea and preview it, the load is correct. Only the is a problem when I select the text inside the textarea and the mouse out the textarea with selection on. Then it tries to load the second (preview) tab.

When I prevent all events on the textarea this behaviour doesn't exists but I also have no preview text.

Could anyone point me the right events to prevent?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this... Seemed the problem was that the switcher component of UIkit allows swiping .... lol